# Validate incomplete Regex

Tags: regex

Let's say we have a Regex, in my case it's one I found to match UK car registration plates:

```
^([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})
```

A typical UK car registration is

```
HG53CAY
```

This is matched correctly by the regex, but what i'd like to do is find a way to match any prefix substring of this, so the following would all be valid:

```
H, HG, HG5, HG53, HG53C, HG53CA, HG53CAY
```

Is there a suggested way to achieve this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: javascript in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd rewrite your regexp to look like this:

```
^([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{1,3})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{1,3})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})
```

as the `\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1}` parts make no sense and should be written `\d{1,3}`.

Rewriting the regexp like

```
^([A-Z]{0,3}\s?(\d{0,3})\s?[A-Z]?)|([A-Z]\s?(\d{0,3})\s?[A-Z]{0,3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y]?)\s?([0]?[2-9]?|[1-9]?[0-9]?)\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{0,3})
```

should have the desired effect of allowing matching of only the beginning of a registration, but unfortunately it's no longer guaranteed that the full registration will be a valid one, as I had to make most characters optional.

You could possibly try something like this

```
^(([A-Z]{3})|[A-Z]{1,2}$)\s?((\d{1,3})|$))...
```

to make it require either that each part is complete, or that it is incomplete but followed by "end of string", represented by the `$` in the regexp.

Comment: Hi Peter, would you be kind enough to extend your example for the part-matching until the very end of the string, my question was phrased a little ambiguously - I have now edited it.

Comment: Hi @ATfPT, sorry for not getting back to you. Did you get it working already by completing my final regexp? Thanks for accepting.